# Difference between JSF FlowScoped and CDI ConversationScoped

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi, jsf-2.2

What are the differences between `javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped` and `javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped` beans and when should either be used in application? Becouse as far as I'm concerned they are somehow similar, but I can not figure it out by the material I found on the Internet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A flow is a group of views related by navigation rules. Flow-scoped beans stay alive as long as you navigate within this flow, and they die when you leave the flow.

Conversation-scoped beans can also survive navigation, but their lifetime is delimited programmatically by calling `Conversation.begin()` and `Conversation.end()`. They are not directly related to a specific group of views.

You can use conversation scoped beans without using JSF.